# Blockmodels using r

Tags: r, classification

I'm trying to classify some biological data using library blockmodels. I got the best model for my datas (with 6 class). The question is how  can i obten the label of each data (labels vectors). This is my code (mat is 132*132 array) :

```
my_model <- BM_poisson("SBM_sym",mat)
my_model$estimate()
which.max(my_model$ICL)
my_model$model_parameters[6]
my_model$plot_obs_pred(6)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
library("network")
library("ramify")
mynet <- as.network(mat)
my_model <- BM_bernoulli("SBM",mat)
my_model$estimate()
#K ist most probable number of classes
K<-which.max(my_model$ICL)
#argmax of Z is the most probable classmemebership
classmembership <-argmax(my_model$memberships[[K]]$Z)
#set classmembership as attribute for plotting
network::set.vertex.attribute(mynet, "Class", classmembership)
```